# How Apache will recognize that a request is from ASP or PHP script?

Tags: php, apache, asp-classic

How Apache will recognize that a request is from **ASP or PHP script**

Comment: Actually - seeing @golja's answer prompts this question: **What do you mean by "from"?** - do you want to detect if the request is coming from a bot written in PHP or ASP, or that the URL has .php or .asp ? This question probably could be improved with an example use case for what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Usually by file extension.

For example in apache you should have lines like that:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
     <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
          SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
     </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the HTTP Response header field "Server" which will tell you something like *Server: Apache/2.4.1 (Unix)*

Furthermore, ASP.NET supplies a non-standard header along the lines of *X-Powered-By:ASP.NET*
 and I know PHP does the same thing (although I can't find the actual message presently.)  Bottom line is look at the HTTP response headers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

I should add that none of these will tell you with 100% certainty (Unix could be running some other server side language in the former example; custom headers can easily be suppressed or even spoofed on the latter example) but it would give you a fairly confident guess as to what you're looking for.